# Databinding Child To Parent to show a Modal Popup

Tags: angular

Trying to pass a boolean to my parent component to display a modal popup onclick. **(Click Event in Child.comp / Modal PopUp in Parent.comp)**
Boolean value never received by parent Component

I've tried @Output() and @Input()
Cant seem to find the problem

Parent.comp.ts | User-Profile

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.scss']
})
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  formPopupUser:boolean = false;

  setPopupActive(){
    this.formPopupUser = !this.formPopupUser;
  }
}
```

Parent.comp.html

```
<div class="modal" (formPopupUser)="setPopupActive()" [ngClass]="formPopupUser === true ? 'popupActive' : ''">
  <form class="modalContent">
    ....
  </form>
</div>
```

Child.comp.ts | User-info

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-info',
  templateUrl: './user-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-info.component.scss']
})

export class UserInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() formPopupUser = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  userInfoNeeded:boolean = true;

  activatePopupUser() {
    this.formPopupUser.emit();
    console.log(this.formPopupUser);
    console.log('im clicked!');
  }

}
```

Child.comp.html

```
<div *ngIf="userInfoNeeded else userInfoAdjust">
    <button (click)="activatePopupUser()" id="createButton" type="button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Gegevens vervolledigen</button>
  </div>
```

Receiving boolean value in parent component so **ngClass(in Parent Comp) gets generated on respected modal pop up**

Answer (score 1):

You need to emit the value and catch the `$event` as an argument.

In the template:

```
(formPopupUser)="setPopupActive($event)"
```

In the sending component:

```
activatePopupUser() {
    this.formPopupUser.emit(this.userInfoNeeded);
    console.log(this.formPopupUser);
    console.log('im clicked!');
}
```

In the receiving component:

```
setPopupActive(b: boolean){
    console.log(b);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not solve my problem:

Argument of type 'EventEmitter<boolean>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'

Comment: My bad, i hurried and got the variables crossed.  The argument for `emit` should have been `this.userInfoNeeded`.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your child component selector in your parent component, instead of 'div' tag there.

> In your Parent.comp.html

```
 <app-user-info class="modal" (formPopupUser)="setPopupActive()" [ngClass]="formPopupUser === true ? 'popupActive' : ''">
  <form class="modalContent">
    ....
  </form>
</app-user-info>
```

> Hope, this solves your problem.